# How to identify image color in java program?

Tags: java

I have a folder with many images with different backgrounds. I have got requirement to sort these images on the basis of background color.

Can I make a java program to read the folder and each image file in there, and decide the image of each file? please share options.

Comment: You have the requirement to sort the images, does that mean to sort them in your file manager like Windows Explorer?

Comment: @Mstodd : I will identify the image background color and put then specific folder. If the image has black background, It should be placed into folder Black.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, it is possible. You can load images with ImageIO.

```
BufferedImage img = ImageIO.read(imageFile);
int rgb = img.getRGB(x,y);
Color color = new Color(rgb);
```

But you have to create an algorithm that finds out which color is the backround color. It depends on the kind of images.

Answer (score 2):

So, not knowing what your images really look like, you may want to average as much of the background as you can to come up with a good representation of the background color.

I would consider a couple things:
* Read in the pixels of each of the four edges.  If there's little variance in the pixel color, then you may be done, just take the average.
* Do the same, but also read in lines from the edge to the middle until you hit a pixel that has a rather different color than your running average.  Do this for all edges.

Those would be the cheapest things that I can think of to cover variances in background color.  Depending on the images you're working with, you may have to get fancier.

A BufferedImage should get you your image data.

Mark